# Robotframework how to do a TextField value should be IN a Loop?

Tags: selenium, for-loop, robotframework

How to have a good loop with a `TextField value shoud be` ?

Here my code :

```
${verifications}              Create List
Set Global Variable           ${verifications}


Input text                    ${societes_input_contact_email}               ${email}
Append To List                ${verifications}                              ${email}

Input text                    ${societes_input_contact_adresse}             ${adresse}
Append To List                ${verifications}                              ${adresse}

Input text                    ${societes_input_site_web}                    ${url_siteweb}
Append To List                ${verifications}                              ${url_siteweb}

FOR    ${item}    IN    @{verifications}
    TextField value shoud be    ${item}
```

But, as you know this keyword need a `locator` + `expected`
So how can I do it in this FOR ?

Thank you

Comment: I saw your previous post around the same problem. you can opt for `Page Should Contain Element` it will require locator only ,but you should use value attribute as part of locator so that you can assert the value inside the text fields Provided each text field should have value attribute associated with it.

Comment: I have to use `Textfield` because page should contain doesn't work 
And the `Page Should Contain Element` is not good to what I need to do.
I need to check if my inputs are filled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two lists, one with the locators and one with the expected values.
Then you can use the [For-in-zip loop](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#for-in-zip-loop) feature to iterate the two lists simultaneously.

> ```
> *** Variables ***
> @{NUMBERS}       ${1}    ${2}    ${5}
> @{NAMES}         one     two     five
>
> *** Test Cases ***
> For-in-zip
>     FOR    ${number}    ${name}    IN ZIP    ${NUMBERS}    ${NAMES}
>         Log Many    ${number}    ${name}
>     END
> ```

A snippet for your use case:

```
*** Variables ***
@{LOCATORS}       xpath1    xpath2    xpath3
@{EXPECTED_VALUES}         one     two     five
```

---

```
FOR    ${locator}    ${expected}    IN ZIP    ${LOCATORS}    ${EXPECTED_VALUES}
    Textfield Value Should Be    ${locator}    ${expected}
END
```

Comment: It works !! So I have one nooby question for you. 
When you wrote a variable in uppercase, like "LOCATORS" here, its for a global variable like "TEST_NAME" ?
And, in this loop, `${locator} and ${expected}` have to be write like this because of their functions ? Or I can write `${a} and ${b}` ?

Comment: @Lidiaz What is in the `*** Variable ***` table is global, but does not matter if it is upper case or lower case. You can go with lower case as well. I am just used to write global variables in all upper case.